# Is CouchDBX still available for download?

Tags: couchdb, couchdbx

If it is, can someone provide me with a download link? I've been looking through google and through the couchbase website, and so far haven't found any reference to the dbx builds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you follow the link from [CouchDBX page](http://janl.github.com/couchdbx/), you will land on Couchbase's site, where to find the OS X binary package under its new name, [Couchbase Server Community Edition](http://www.couchbase.com/downloads/couchbase-server/community) (direct link to download page).

This is were I got it, at least.

Answer (score 3):

Couchbase is different from CouchDB, so if you can't use it in your shop (like me), CouchDBX is still available here:

http://dl.couchone.com/dl/384fe8cac77f981551a6632c020259a3/CouchDBX-1.0.2.0.zip

(Please don't take it down :-)